# Wrap html element with Divs from custom directive

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an `<input />` tag which I want to wrap with some specific `Div` tags. I'm making custom directive in which I want to implement this functionality. But the problem which I'm facing is, `element`'s `prepend()` method adds the whole tag i.e. it starts and ends before the targeted `input` tag. Similarly, `append()` method on `element` appends the `Div` inside the `input` tag, while what I actually want is,

**On html:**

```
<input id="oldinput" custom-textbox />  <!-- custom-textbox is my directive -->
```

**After applying directive, in source, I want this:**

```
<div id="mynewdiv>   <!-- added from directive -->
    <input id="oldinput" custom-textbox />   <!-- present input tag where I'd apply my directive -->
    <div id="othernewdiv" />    <!-- new div to be added from directive -->
</div>    <!-- end of newly added div from directive  -->
```

**But the result after using `append()` and `prepend()` functions:**

```
<div id="mynewdiv> </div>   <!-- added from directive, div ends here only -->
<input id="oldinput" custom-textbox >   <!-- present input tag where I'd apply my directive, doesn't end here -->
    <div id="othernewdiv" />    <!-- new div to be added from directive, it's added inside input tag -->
    </div>    <!-- end of newly added div from directive  -->
</input>    <!-- Wraps my newly added div -->
```

Completely strange behavior. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`wrap()` does exactly what you want:

```
// wrap the input with a div
element.wrap('<div id="mynewdiv></div> ')
// add the second div
element.parent().append('<div id="othernewdiv" />')
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. But now this newly added element is not getting compiled. I have posted this question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051494/newly-added-elements-from-angular-directive-not-getting-compiled. Why is it not getting compiled? How should I make it work so that the `div` shows the angular changes there?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [ngTransclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) and also the [Developper Guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

> **Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements**
>
> We've seen that you can pass in models to a directive using the
>   isolate scope, but sometimes it's desirable to be able to pass in an
>   entire template rather than a string or an object. Let's say that we
>   want to create a "dialog box" component. The dialog box should be able
>   to wrap any arbitrary content.

Comment: Is it like `transclude` can be used with templates only? For my requirement, I have to use the attributes that will be passed with the directive and because of that, I have written `link` function that gets the attributes. Is there any way with `ngTranclude` to get attributes and give the template which is using those attributes?