# Newly added elements from angular directive not getting compiled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrapped my `input` tag with some `div` tags as per the requirement. Now the issue is, class of `div` tag is changing dynamically by angular, but seems this newly added `div` is not getting compiled and because of that, it is shown on the page (saw in view source in browser) exactly as I add it. No change is happening which it usually does if I add it directly on page instead of from directive.

I tried adding `{{ name }}` also in this `div` but it also doesn't print the name property while adding it directly on page, does work. This gave me the conclusion that the newly added `div` is not getting compiled properly.

I'm calling from html like this,

```
<!-- ag-textbox is my directive -->
<input ag-textbox ag-grid-class="col-md-4" class="form-control" id="age" type="text"  ag-name="Age" ng-model="age" ag-formname="newform" required />
```

My code in js is,

```
var fDiv = angular.element("<div class='" + agGridClass + "' "
                            + "ng-class={'has-error':" + agFormName + "." + agName + ".$invalid}>");
element.wrap(fDiv);
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

It was working when I wasn't using `wrap()` function as below:

```
element.html('').append(firstDiv + inputText + otherDiv);
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

This was working fine but now my requirement is different and I have to wrap the existing `input` tag so have to use the `wrap()` function.

I have tried `$compile(element)(scope)` and `$compile(element.html())(scope)` but none of them work as well. Is there any way to compile the newly added components?

Comment: looks like something is wrong while appending contents.can you share the fiddle.

Comment: Sorry didn't get you. You mean whole link function and html code?

Comment: Done. Let me know if anything else is required. The div is wrapped exactly I wrap it statically on page but from here, when added, it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 2):

After calling `.wrap()`, `element` is still a reference to the original DOM element, which doesn't include div that it is wrapped in. So when you compile `element`, the wrapped div is not compiled.

Assuming `fDiv` is a simple div, you can try using `.parent()` to include it in the compilation...

```
element.wrap(fDiv);
$compile(element.parent().contents())(scope);
```

Edit...

fDiv appears to be missing `"`s in the ng-class attribute and needs a closing `</div>` tag...

```
var fDiv = angular.element("<div class='" + agGridClass + "' "
               + "ng-class=\"{'has-error':" + agFormName + "." + agName + ".$invalid}\"></div>");
```

Comment: I assument `element..parent()` should be replaced by `element.parent()` here. And this also doesn't work. It goes into infinite loop and page stops working. I've put my `fDiv` var in my question.

Comment: No, not working. `<div class="col-md-4" ng-class="{'has-error':newform.Age.$invalid}"><input ag-textbox="" ag-grid-class="col-md-4" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="age" type="text" name="Age" ng-model="age" required=""></div>` This is the code got from `Inspect Element`. Double quotes are added automatically for the attributes, no need to add them externally. Also, it works perfectly fine when added exactly like this statically on page.